# Embed OTF font in PDF Document

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

Is there a way to include an OTF font in a PDF document using Apache PDFBox (2.0) ?

It seems only TTF fonts are supported by this library.

Here is the exception i encounter when i try to load an OTF font:

```
PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(pdf, 
    new File("/home/ben/.fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf"));
```

which throws:

```
java.io.IOException: loca is mandatory
        at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:210)
        at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:150)
        at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:87)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.load(PDType0Font.java:65)
```

Comment: The font is available from google https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro as .ttf

Comment: I found it in an alternative github repo. Thanks @TilmanHausherr for the official pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Non support of OTF fonts by PDFBOX is confirmed by the [PDFBOX-2482](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2482) JIRA issue "Support for creating PDF containing OTF fonts".

**EDIT**

As mentionned by @TilmanHausherr, the font is [available as a TTF](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro) and can be used as a workaround