# pdfbox generates garbage japanese text if it contains kangxi radicals

Tags: unicode, pdfbox

we use pdfbox 2.0.20 and try to generate pdf file that contains following text with NotoSansJP(https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+JP). note that `⽤` in the text does not valid kanji (`0xe794a8`), this is  [kangxi radical use](https://graphemica.com/%E2%BD%A4)(`0xe2bda4`)

```
注文書兼注文請書Webページのボタン⽤GIF画像編集
```

result become below garbled text.

[image]

strange thing is if I copy-and-paste these garbled text in pdf here, result seems correct.

```
注⽂書兼注⽂請書Webページのボタン用GIF画像編集
```

except that `用` in the text become valid kanji(`0xe794a8`).

so, for me it seems that when text contains invalid kanji like kangxi radicals, different code pages are used.
but the fact that kangxi radical character seems to be modified to valid kanji, maybe it related with unicode normalization.

Does anyone experience same situation? and any thought about the reason?

regards,

EDIT: our nervous customer complains the problematic text contains **sensitive** data, I change the text a bit.

Comment: please retry with 2.0.25. If it still doesn't work, create a small reproducer and create an issue in PDFBox JIRA.

Comment: hi, I created reproducer with kotlin https://github.com/umegaya/pdfbox-test but I found following log appears (original code reports same warning, but I overlooked them because original code have a lot of log output) ```警告: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored``` so I think pdfbox just does not support file format that NotoSanJP provides. any plan to support the format?

Comment: I'm not sure if otf is supported at all. Maybe try converting the font to ttf.

Comment: It's a no: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051628/embed-otf-font-in-pdf-document